# .Net Core API method not calling

Tags: asp.net-core, routes

I have an Asp.Net Core API. The method that I'm trying to call looks like this:

```
[ApiController]   
public class DataController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("[controller]/[action]/{data}")]
    public async Task<bool> GetData(Data data)
    {
```

I'm trying to call the API from a method similar to the following:

```
private async Task<bool> CallData(Data data)
{
    var dataString = new StringContent(
        JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data), 
        Encoding.UTF8,
        "application/json");
    var response = await client.PostAsync(
        $"https://localhost:1111/data/getdata", dataString);
    return (response.IsSuccessStatusCode);
}
```

For some reason, I simply can't get the method to fire. My guess is that the routing is at fault, but I'm clearly missing something, as the routing seems fine to me.

EDIT:

I have also tried the following route:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("[controller]/[action]")]
public async Task<bool> GetData(Data data)
{
```

But that also doesn't work.

EDIT:

The following is the startup code for the API:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllers();

    services.AddSingleton<MyConfiguration>(service => new MyConfiguration()
    {
        ConfigValue1 = Configuration.GetValue("MyConfigValue1"),
        ConfigValue2 = Configuration.GetValue("MyConfigValue2"),
    });

    services.AddScoped<IMyHelper, MyHelper>();
    services.AddHttpClient();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseRouting();  
    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllers();
    });
}
```

Comment: I have tested your codes on my side, it works well. The url is right. You should make sure the localhost:1111 is right.  Could you please tell me how you host the web api inside IIS or just debug in the VS?

Comment: It's self hosted. I think it is finding the endpoint - it's just not executing it for some reason

Comment: Is there any action filter or middleware in your application?

Comment: @BrandoZhang - No - nothing at all

Comment: Could you please post the startup.cs codes? I guess there is some custom middleware or else which cause this issue.

Comment: I've added the startup code, but there's essentially nothing there that you don't get out of the box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have declared `data` to be part of the url in `Route`. In your call you pass `dataString` as the **body** of the `POST` request. The body must not be part of the route declaration though, only parts of the url should be.

You have to remove `{data}` from the `Route`.

Comment: It doesn't seem to make any difference. I've updated my question.

Comment: Does your `Data` class have the correct shape/are you using the same class in the client and in the controller?

Comment: It has the same shape, but the class is not shared (it's a copy / paste)

Comment: How about chaning route to `Route("data/getdata")` i.e. "hard code" to make sure the config isn't the issue? Also, are you sure about `https://localhost:1111`. You could also enable `trace` log level and watch the server's console/log output. There you see what routing does,

Comment: Neither of these make any difference.  However, I tried injecting a log message into the endpoint routing, and it looks like it does find the correct endpoint - it just never executes it.

Answer (score 1):

The answer in the end was that I wasn't specifying one of the values for `data`, and so it was being passed through as `null`. This seemed to cause the endpoint not to fire, despite it finding it (presumably because it couldn't deserialise it?)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `FromBody` attribute before action method argument

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("[controller]/[action]")]
public async Task<bool> GetData([FromBody]Data data)
```

Comment: Adding FromBody makes no difference